# Pop up Windows Form in WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a form developed in Windows Forms and I am working in a WPF project.
I am trying to pop up a window (ManoeuvresForm) when I click in a specific button.

This is what I am using:

```
    private void button_newProject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid_initialButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        grid_projectConfig.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ManoeuvresForm.ActiveForm.Show();  
    }
```

I have add the form to the solution tree already.
 [Solution Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffB4L.png)

When I try to run it says that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I am not a coding expert, just trying to learn from Google :)

Thanks!

Comment: You need to instantiate the form first before displaying it

Comment: try "ManoevresForm frm=new ManoeversForm(); frm.show;" instead. As Alex mentioned instantiation is the key here. ActiveForm needs to be set separately if you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it comes out with this message "Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" @lsteinme

Comment: Fixed! I was missing the () after the frm.show
Thanks guys!